# How do I ignore the content of a message?

Tags: citrus-framework

Is there a chance to not validate the contents and headers of a message, i.e. just check if a message is present & consume it?
When I do just a "receive", it is automatically assumed that I want to validate XML content.
I just want to consume the message (from a queue in my use case) which is not relevant to my test. But I would like to get it off the queue. I could purge it in the next test run but I would rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expected control message payload is really empty the message validation should be skipped.

XML DSL

```
<receive endpoint="jmsQueueEndpoint">
  <message></message>
</receive>
```

Java DSL

```
receive(jmsQueueEndpoint);
```

However it should also be mentioned that receiving messages in a test that are not relevant to the test is a bad thing